# Using downloaded Java class files in Android app

Tags: java, android, apk

Let's assume we have an installed Android app.

Is it possible to download a Java class file over a network, or to get it from app resources and then use some functionality that's provided by this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you shoud read this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) on Android Developers site.